# How to know who checked-in on behalf of another user (using /author)

Tags: version-control, tfs

In TFS2010, one can checkin on behalf of another user (assuming he has permission to do so):

```
> tf.exe checkin (...) /author:OtherUser
```

Checkin history shows OtherUser as the user who made the checkin:

```
> tf history (...) /noprompt
Changeset User              Date       Comment
--------- ----------------- ---------- -----------
1234      OtherUser         (...)
```

I found a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/03/20/checkin.aspx) saying "*Both your user name and OtherUser are recorded in the changeset data, so that you can always determine who checked in the changes*". I presume it's recorded in [Changeset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset_properties%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).Commiter vs ChangeSet.Owner, but `tf history` or `tf changeset` don't display that.

Is there some UI/tool that displays this info?

[edit] Note: Seems that Commiter can mean 2 different things:

1. User that checked-in on behalf of OtherUser, using `tf checkin /author`.
2. User that runs gated checkin (machine account or build user).

In case one made a `tf checkin /author` into a gated checkin, then meaning 1 wins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, there are two different users involved.

1. [`Changeset.Committer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset.committer.aspx) - The user who actually performed the check-in (i.e. the user who was authenticated to the server)
2. [`Changeset.Owner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset.owner.aspx) - The user who the check-in was performed on behalf of (i.e. specified as `/author:OtherUser`)

The Visual Studio UI will not show you the two different users involved. It will only show you the Owner/Author. (Which makes sense, since it's rare that the committer would be different)

If you want to see both users, you can use the following command-line, with the /noprompt switch to force the output to the console:

```
C:\code>tf changeset 1234 /noprompt
Changeset: 1234
User: ChangesetOwnerOrAuthorUser
Checked in by: ChangesetCommitterUser
Date: Friday, 1 February 2013 12:00:00 PM

Comment:

Items:
  edit $/project/test/test.txt
```

Comment: That's right, never noticed `tf changeset /noprompt`. Thanks!